# Meaning of this symbol: "inverted product"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation, terminology

I am reading algebraic geometry from notes of a senior and I am struck on this terminalogy.

Question: In the definition of Closed subvarities of $\mathbb{P}^n$, the author write $\mathbb{P}^n= \coprod_{i=0}^n S_i$, where $S_i$ is a locally closed and isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^i$. I don't understand what the symbol $\coprod_{i=0}^n$ represents?

Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Generally the symbol $\coprod$ means the coproduct in whichever ambient category you find yourself (provided it exists, of course). In the case of the category $\mathbf{Sch}_{/S}$ of $S$-schemes or $\mathbf{Var}_{/K}$ of $K$-varieties the coproduct is disjoint union of the listed schemes/varieties (although you do need to be sure that it is a finite disjoint union for the variety case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol $\coprod$ (`$\coprod$`) is used to denote the coproduct (ref [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct), [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coproduct), and many other sources).